# Unable to show multiple tooltips upon click in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, internet-explorer-11

please help to resolve the following issue.
I am trying to display multiple tooltips on button click and hide them on second button click. For some reason I cannot do it in IE 11. In the example that i provide I can perfectly display them on page load by default. Once I try to do it on click (code commented out) nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Demo</h3>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip is visible!">Tooltip will be visible here</a>

        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip is visible!">Tooltip will be visible here</a>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Tooltip</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hide Tooltip</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        //works fine  I can see tooltips by default
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('show');

        $(document).ready(function () {
 
    $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
       //  doesn't work for some reson
      //  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
       // $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('show');
    });
    $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('hide');
    });
        });

      
           
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so it works in real browsers? is there any errors in the **developer** tools console of your so called browser?

Comment: And what does happen...define "doesn't work" in more technical detail

Comment: @JaromandaX Back to *steam powered* browser issues huh? :)

Comment: I have edited my question .  I don't see any errors on the console of my browser.  I expect to see 2 tooltips on button click and expect them to disappear on hide button click. yes it works in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Demo</h3>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip is visible!">Tooltip will be visible here</a>

        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip is visible!">Tooltip will be visible here</a>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Tooltip</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hide Tooltip</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        //make sure to comment this lines
        //works fine  I can see tooltips by default
      //  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
       // $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('show');

        $(document).ready(function () {
 
    $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
        // works fine on IE11
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('show');
    });
    $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip('hide');
    });
    });

      
           
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. this suppose to work. doesn't work in IE 11 though . and it's very frustrating .

Comment: Try using the above snippet I have just checked on IE 11.

Comment: It works now. I believe the problem was not in browser but in layout page of my project.

Comment: Should provide explanation for what was changed and why...not just in comments, so it is clear to all readers right away